# Django - Render is not working in my project

Tags: django, forms, render

I am dealing with form like 1 week but couldn't solve my issue. Probably i overlook something that can be found easy by other eyes, but totally, i don't know what to do. I recognize problem by starting build form. I had to use `render` for form and it failed in every try. I am able to connect db and showing data in html pages but whenever i use `render` instead of `render_to_response` it is failing. And i had to use `render` for post request as i know. Not only for form, `render` is not working for all. Even for a simple: `def home(request): context = {'foo': 'bar'} return render(request, 'main.html', context)`

models.py

```
class ModuleNames(models.Model):
    ModuleName = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ModuleDesc = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    ModuleSort = models.SmallIntegerField()
    isActive = models.BooleanField()
    ModuleType = models.ForeignKey(ModuleTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(('ModuleName'), max_length=50, blank=True)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'zz'
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.status
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from MyApp.models import ModuleNames

class ModuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    moduleName = forms.CharField(label='Module Name', max_length=50)
    ModuleDesc = forms.CharField(max_length = 256)
    ModuleSort = forms.IntegerField()
    isActive = forms.BooleanField()
    ModuleType = forms.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    model = ModuleNames
    fields =('moduleName','ModuleDesc','ModuleSort','isActive','ModuleType')
```

view.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from django.urls import resolve 
from django.db import connection
from collections import namedtuple
from django.db.models import F
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

from MyApp.models import ModuleNames
from MyApp.forms import ModuleForm

def AddNewModule(request):
    template_name = 'addnewmodule.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ModuleForm()
        posts = ModuleNames.objects.all()
        args = {'form': form, 'posts': posts }
        return render(request, template_name, args) #This part is showing data when i use render_to_response. But after clicking Save button on html page, it will give below first error.

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModuleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken', None)
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = ModuleForm()
            args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
            return render(request, template_name, args)
```

1. Error that i have when using `render_to_response`
   Forbidden (403)
   CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

   Help
   Reason given for failure:
   CSRF token missing or incorrect.
2. Error when i use `render` for any function

   ```
       Environment:
   Request Method: GET
   Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/addnewmodule

   Django Version: 2.1.3
   Python Version: 3.7.1
   Installed Applications:
   ['MyApp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles']
   Installed Middleware:
   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

   Traceback:

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
   34.response = get_response(request)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
   126.response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
   124.response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

   File "/Users/Cem/Documents/Projects/Python/Web/FirstApp/MyApp/views.py" in addnewmodule
   132.return render(request, template_name, args)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
   36.content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
   62.return template.render(context, request)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
   61.return self.template.render(context)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
   169.with context.bind_template(self):

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py" in __enter__
   112.return next(self.gen)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in bind_template
   246.updates.update(processor(self.request))

   Exception Type: TypeError at /addnewmodule
   Exception Value: 'module' object is not callable
   ```

Comment: `render_to_response` is old and deprecated. It will be removed after a few versions. Don't use it. Only use `render`.

Comment: @xyres i know but `render` is not working in any where of the project.

Comment: Can you put this code at the top of your view and tell me what's the output in the terminal -  `print(type(render))`. You'll have to make a request to your view for it to print something.

Comment: why are you using `pop` for `csrf_tokens` ? Try again after removing `pop` method.

Comment: It is not helping. BTW, i created new project from scratch and used same functions in new project then all worked fine. I don't know what i broke in old project but i will 
 compare both of them and if couldn't find what is wrong then will create new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [CSRF tokens](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/) in django, it's used for site protection/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the the `csrf_token` in your `addnewmodule.html` form, so,
you can get back to `addnewmodule.html` form and add the `{% csrf_token %}`just below the tag `form action="" method="POST"` like this

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
```